# Implementing Chinese Remainder Theorem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, crt

I have been trying to solve [Advent of Code 2020 day 13](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/13) part 2 task. I found a lot of hints talking about something called [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chinese-remainder-theorem/). I have tried some implementations following npm's [nodejs-chinesse-remainders](https://github.com/pnicorelli/nodejs-chinese-remainder/blob/master/chinese_remainder.js) but this implementation seems to be quite old (2014) and also requires extra libraries for Big Int cases.

How could I implement the modular multiplicative inverse ? How could I refactor the CRT algorithm define in the npm module for which I provided a link?

Comment: AoC, teaching programmers about the CRT since 2016

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a self response and with the purpose of make a wiki to find this solution for those who in the future need a CRT implementation in javascript/typescript:

First think is to implement [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), for this task what we try to find is an x such that:
`a*x % modulus = 1`

```js
const modularMultiplicativeInverse = (a: bigint, modulus: bigint) => {
  // Calculate current value of a mod modulus
  const b = BigInt(a % modulus);
    
    // We brute force the search for the smaller hipothesis, as we know that the number must exist between the current given modulus and 1
    for (let hipothesis = 1n; hipothesis <= modulus; hipothesis++) {
        if ((b * hipothesis) % modulus == 1n) return hipothesis;
    }
      // If we do not find it, we return 1
    return 1n;
}
```

Then following the article and the sample code you gave:

```js
const solveCRT = (remainders: bigint[], modules: bigint[]) => {
    // Multiply all the modulus
    const prod : bigint = modules.reduce((acc: bigint, val) => acc * val, 1n);
    
    return modules.reduce((sum, mod, index) => {
        // Find the modular multiplicative inverse and calculate the sum
    // SUM( remainder * productOfAllModulus/modulus * MMI ) (mod productOfAllModulus) 
        const p = prod / mod;
        return sum + (remainders[index] * modularMultiplicativeInverse(p, mod) * p);
    }, 0n) % prod;
}
```

This way you use ES6 functions such as `reduce`

For this to work with bigints the array of remainders and modules should correspond to a ES2020's [BigInt](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint)

E.g:

```
  x mod 5 = 1
  x mod 59 = 13
  x mod 24 = 7
```

```js
// Declare the problem and execute function
// You can not parse them to BigInt here, but TypeScript will complain of operations between int and bigint
const remainders : bigint[] = [1, 13, 7].map(BigInt)
const modules: bigint[] = [5, 59, 24].map(BigInt)

solveCRT(remainders, modules) // 6031
```